# Firefox, Chrome CSS positioning issues

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, browser, xhtml

In Firefox and Chrome the Table Booking widget seems to be aligned with the website. But I have been told that it is not inline in Firefox and Chrome. But I can't seem to replicate this can anyone shed any light on this please.

http://www.thewhiteoak.co.uk/

Answer (score 1):

In your index.html file on line 199 you have special -moz style:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
.OT_wrapper {
margin: -10px 0 5px 450px;
}
```

You should add this margin margin: -10px 0 5px 450px;  for .OT_wrapper   to Chrome too.

Answer (score 0):

```
.OT_wrapper {
    background-color: rgb(246, 246, 243);
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
.OT_wrapper {
margin:-10px 0 5px 0px;
}
}
```

to

```
.OT_wrapper {
margin:-10px 0 5px 0px;
}
```